# CSV to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo, ftp

Here, I want to insert record from csv to mysql database but result goes blank.
I have csv to insert the record in mysql but result goes blank.
Here when I am going to run this file, it shows blank.
Where is the problem?

import.php:

```
function connect() {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'test';
    $db_user = 'abc';
    $db_password = '1234';
    return new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}

$pdo = connect();

$ftp_server= "ftp.com";
$euuser = "ftpusername";
$eupassword = "ftppwd";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $euuser, $eupassword);
$path=ftp_pwd($conn_id)."magento_prd/orderitems100050284.csv";

//echo "hello".$conn_id;
//exit;
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);

foreach ($contents as $file)
{

  echo "<br>$file";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);

//exit;
//echo "hello";exit;
function insert_read_file($file){
$csv_file =$file;

    if (is_file($csv_file)) {

         if ($_FILES['csv_file']['size'] <= 0) {

            $errorMsg.="Please select tab delimited .txt";
            die();

        } else {
            $upload_file_extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));

            if (strtolower($upload_file_extension) != 'txt') {
                echo "not txt file";
                die();
            }
        }
        $column=Array ('Full Name','Source','Order ReferenceNum','Postal Service Name','Tracking Number','SourceUserName' ,'Phone Number');

        if (($input = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            $row = fgetcsv($input, 1024, ','); 
            $re=array_diff($column,$row);
            if(sizeof($re)!=0)
            {
                $errorMsg='csv not matched';
            }    
            if(sizeof($row)==1){
                $errorMsg='csv is blank';
            }
            $count = 0;
            while (($row = fgetcsv($input)) !== FALSE) {
                //print_r($row);
                echo "</br>";

                $sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_order_details(order_id, orderdet_productsku, orderdet_iscase, orderdet_qty, item_sold_price) VALUES'
                        . '(:order_id, :orderdet_productsku, :orderdet_iscase, :orderdet_qty, :item_sold_price)';

                        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                        $query->bindParam(':order_id', $row[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $query->bindParam(':orderdet_productsku', $row[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $query->bindParam(':orderdet_iscase',$row[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $query->bindParam(':orderdet_qty', $row[3],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $query->bindParam(':item_sold_price', $row[4],PDO::PARAM_STR);

                        $query->execute();

                $count++;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
         $errorMsg='not csv';
    }
}
```

Comment: Before insert statement, try displaying the values. Check whether the values are set or not,

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_order_details(order_id, orderdet_productsku, orderdet_iscase, orderdet_qty, item_sold_price) VALUES'
   . '(:order_id, :orderdet_productsku, :orderdet_iscase, :orderdet_qty, :item_sold_price)';
```

to below code:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_order_details ( order_id, orderdet_productsku, orderdet_iscase, orderdet_qty, item_sold_price) 
        VALUES(:order_id,:orderdet_productsku,:orderdet_iscase,:orderdet_qty,:item_sold_price)';
```

**NOTE:** No need to use **`(.) period`** before `VALUES`.

Or **better** to use like:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_order_details SET order_id = :order_id,
        orderdet_productsku = :orderdet_productsku, orderdet_iscase = :orderdet_iscase, 
        orderdet_qty = :orderdet_qty, item_sold_price = :item_sold_price';
```